# NSIS script to copy files silently without any GUI?

Tags: nsis

My Nsis script is copying files from one location to other on target machine. Its showing a box like copying files c:\programfiles.... to c:\programfiles.... .
I dont want the end user to see this box. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CopyFiles /SILENT "c:\foo" "d:\bar"
```

Comment: Thanks Anders you have been very helpful to me

Comment: @Anders This copies the Folder foo into bar and it becomes D:bar\foo, how can I just copy the contents  of C:\foo into d:\bar?

Comment: @wintersolider `c:\foo\*`

Comment: @Anders That worked thanks and I have edited the answer so that anyone that has similar requirement can easily get the answer.